# Execute jquery mobile code when changing code

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, execute

I have this code

```
<div data-role="content">

<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-r">
       <li><a href="#info" >Information</a></li>
       <li><a href="#startLopen" >Start met lopen</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How can I tell my application to execute code when the user has pressed the "Information" button?

My attemps to try it, failed all
For example:

```
$('#liInfo').click(generateInfo);
function generateInfo()
{
alert("It works!");
}
```

Comment: I fail to see *any* attempts. http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have jquery included before this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#info').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("It works");
   });

});
```

Or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

          var clickFunc = function(){
              alert("works!");
          }

          $('a#info').click(clickFunc);
   });
```

Comment: I did that, I just didn't mention it here

    $(document).ready(function() {


    $('#navBrugge').click(gekozenBrugge);
    $('#navKortrijk').click(gekozenKortrijk);
    $('#navGent').click(gekozenGent);
    $('#liInfo').click(generateInfo);
     });

    function genereerInfo()
    {
 alert("It works!");
    }

Comment: you must first declare the function, and then call it. Switch the order

Comment: That works!
I'm a but confused, because of my other code, I call them first, then declare them